# Flutter local notifications in the background

Tags: flutter, dart, notifications, background-process, flutter-notification

We have an app that probes an api endpoint periodically (every 60 seconds) and provides data to a user.

Currently we are using a Timer function and Observing the state of the app (whether its in foreground, background etc) and if it's in the background, we are calling the timer function every 60 seconds, probing the api endpoint, filtering through the results of that api call to find any new events and then if new events are found, sending a flutter local notification using your plugin.

However currently even though new events are found, the local notifications are not being sent through consistently in a release version (but they are in debug version).

We were wondering what the issue would be or if there was a simpler way to just use the flutter local notification plugin somehow in the background when a new event is found.

I have a suspicion that the OS stopping them from running in the background, however if that is the case, how do apps such as google maps or Waze maps, how do they run in the background without the OS stopping them.

Any help is appreciated as I've spent hours on this issue.

Comment: Anyone got any ideas?